# Not navigating to the desired route in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This is my routing configuration

```
      <BrowserRouter>
      <ToastContainer autoClose={3000}  />
        <HeaderComponent />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={!user ? <SignInOutPage /> : <Navigate to={"/home"} />} />
          
          <Route element={<ProtectedRoute user={user} />}>
            <Route path="shop" element={<ShopPage />} />
            <Route path="shop/:name" element={<CollectionPageComp />} />
            <Route path="home" element={<Homepage />} />
            <Route path="checkout" element={<CheckOutPage />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
          </Route>

        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

The issue i am facing is that when i am on home page, I want to navigate to "localhost:3000/shop/:name", But It keeps redirecting me to "localhost:3000/home/shop/:name" because i am navigating from "/home". Can anyone help?
This is my navigating code.

```
const MenuItems = ({item}) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <>
      <div className={`${item.size} menu-item`} onClick={() => navigate(`shop/${item.title}`)}>
      <div className="background-image" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${item.imageUrl})` }}/>
        <div className="content">
          <h1 className="title">{item.title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
          <span className="subtitle">Shop Now</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

I have tried all the solutions online but with this react router 6, the issue is still not fixed.

Comment: could it be you are navigating while !user ?
cause then it first navigates to home: 
<Route path="/" element={!user ? <SignInOutPage /> : <Navigate to={"/home"} />} />

Comment: Do you need a forward slash `navigate(`/shop/${item.title}`

Comment: @Azzy omg I can't believe it. Thank you so much for taking the time. forward slash was missing which was causing all the trouble. Issue resolved!

Comment: Thank you @tomer_Ra to you too for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved! I was missing a slash in front of the desired location. onClick={() => navigate(`/shop/${item.title}`)}.